# Load FaunaDB documents within date range

Tags: faunadb

I have a collection of meals which contain a date field 'date'. I want to query all meals within a specific date range. I struggle to build a FQL query that returns the whole documents for the use in a user generated function to be consumed in a GraphQL query.

What i have:

Index 'mealsByDate':

```
{
  name: "mealsByDate",
  unique: false,
  serialized: true,
  source: "Meal",
  terms: [],
  values: [
    {
      field: ["data", "date"]
    },
    {
      field: ["ref"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
Paginate(Range(Match(Index("mealsByDate")), Date("2019-12-30"), Date("2020-01-05")))
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      Date("2019-12-30"),
      Ref(Collection("Meal"), "253389516394463764")
    ],
    [
      Date("2019-12-30"),
      Ref(Collection("Meal"), "253389626235945490")
    ],
    [
      Date("2020-01-05"),
      Ref(Collection("Meal"), "253389653063762452")
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can i get the documents of the refs in the result set? I tried to put the Paginate function into a Map function and apply a Lambda which does a Get, but i'm not able to select the ref in the result. Or is the whole approach flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you paginate results from an index that contains multiple `value` fields, each result is an array of the specified values from the indexed document. As your query demonstrated, your index returns arrays with 2 values that contain the date and document ref.

When you wrap your query with `Map`, the lambda function that you provide must accept the same number of arguments, like so:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Range(
      Match(Index("mealsByDate")),
      Date("2019-12-30"),
      Date("2020-01-05")
    )
  ),
  Lambda(
    ["d", "r"],
    Get(Var("r"))
  )
)
```

With that query, the date field as passed as the argument `d`, and the ref is passed as the argument `r`. That makes it easy to access the ref, using the `Var` function.

When you use `Map` to iterate over other structures that might include an array, you can use the `Select` function to access numbered elements of the array. See https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/select for more details.